# Can't seem to get each div table box to have the same equal height

Tags: html, css, css-tables

More or less, working on a table through CSS and divs and have it mostly set, except for some reason the height isn't uniform and changes for each box. Have tried various height changes and commands with no luck.  Not sure if the issue is with the CSS below or a conflict with some of the other CSS coding.

CSS:

```
.collection{
    width:600px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.collection td{
    padding:5px;
}
.collection-box{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px 2px;
    border-color:#29FDF1;
    background: rgba(11, 14, 15, .65)
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 5px;
}
.collection-innerbox{
    display:inline-block;
    background: rgba(11, 14, 15, .65)
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.collection-text{
    text-align:center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mhxjp27/)
[Full site's CSS on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/x8Nt70wZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `vertical-align` value to `top` and add a `100% height` to the main inner div and it works :)

```
.collection td { vertical-align: top; }
.collection-box { height: 100% }
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1mhxjp27/3/)

**Note :** Be careful, you forgot a comma after your background value here :

```
.collection-innerbox{
    display:inline-block;
    background: rgba(11, 14, 15, .65)
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, no need to add the two CSS lines I've provide, just this typo fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

You're close enough. you need to put the border on '.collection td' not on '.collection-box'

```
.collection td {
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px;
    border-color: #29FDF1;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And if you need space between them,

```
.collection td {
   vertical-align: top; 
  }
 .collection-box { 
   height: 100% 
  }
```